# Git is referencing an old version of Xcode

Tags: xcode, git

A little while ago during the iOS 7/Xcode 5 betas I installed the Xcode 5 preview in parallel with the latest version of Xcode 4.x. The application was named `Xcode 2`. I have since deleted `Xcode 2`.

My problem is that now when I try to use `git mergetool -t opendiff` it gives this error.

```
xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory)
```

How can I change the version of Xcode that `mergetool` looks at when it tries to use `opendiff`?

Comment: What do you get when you do this in terminal "echo $DEVELOPER_DIR" .  Do you get something unexpected? If so, maybe try setting it to your preferred Xcode. You could also try running git as xcrun git, that will make xcrun find the right version of git for your active sdk.

Comment: @darren I get an empty line as the response. I guess you could call that unexpected. I tried setting the correct Xcode using "sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app" and that has worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app` to select the correct version of Xcode it should be using as per @darren's suggestion.